# eu estou tendo problemas ao iniciar o React

Tags: react, react-native, react-hooks, react-dom, rxjs

ao tentar iniciar o react ele diz que "package.json" não esta sendo encontrado em "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Projeto-QUIS-main"; irei colocar imagens abaixo para ajudar a identificar, irei colocar um print tentando iniciar com "yarn start" e a outra com "npm start"
[npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fi1e.png)
[yarn start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv7sV.png)

Comment: Você rodou npm install antes?

Comment: Obs: "quiz" é um termo em inglês, e se escreve  com Z

Answer (score -3):

Perceba que você tem duas pastas com o mesmo nome: "Projeto-QUIS-main". O seu package.json existe, mas ele está na segunda pasta "Projeto-QUIS-main". Você atualmente está na primeira pasta. Então a solução é você mover para a segunda pasta e executar novamente `npm start` ou `yarn start`.